# ¿Cómo enviar los datos que alamacena una variable en jQuery mediante AJAX a un PHP y guardar en la base de datos con MySQLi?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Estoy realizando un contador en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) de cuántos usuarios en línea están viendo una pregunta. Ejemplo: Pedro y Juan y una persona más están viendo está pregunta. La variable `user_online` almacena los nombres de los usuarios en línea. Utilizo [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) porque por medio AJAX quiero refrescar los usuarios online.

```js
var user_online = ["Pedro", "Juan", "Carlos"];
```

Mi pregunta es cómo hago, al presionar un botón de la página, enviar el valor de esta variable, recogiendo los valores en PHP y guardándolo en la base de datos mediante [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli), siguiendo esta estructura:

```
 id    User_Online
----  ---------------------
 1     Pedro, Juan, Carlos
```

Comment: Hola @May. ¡Bienvenido/a a [es.so]! Consulta: ¿Por qué lo estás haciendo desde JavaScript, y no directamente en el servidor? Veo que etiquetaste [php], quizás sería mucho más efectivo y directo hacerlo con PHP, cada vez que se accede a la página...Por otro lado, no me queda claro qué estás preguntando sobre el final. ¿Qué estás queriendo hacer con esa URL?

Comment: Hola @Mariano gracias etiquete php y mysqli porqué no se muy bien cómo guardar los datos almacenado que contiene la variable `user_online = [];` es muy diferente programar solo con php utilizo jquery porque por medio ajax refresco los usurios online ejemplo  Pedro y juan y uno más esta viendo esta pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano no se cómo explicar en el registro de la base de datos se encuentra tres nombres continuos como puedo generar un enlace de cada uno de los nombre individual en un registro dónde están los tres nombres juntos en la misma columna

Comment: Sería algo como esto: https://jsfiddle.net/z8xvzct7/ .. Sin embargo, no termino de entender si eso es lo que estás preguntando o hay algo más.

Comment: Si vas a guardar en la base de datos, no entiendo por qué lo estás implementando en JavaScript. Si la idea es grabar usuarios online, quizás conviene hacerlo directamente en PHP, sin depender de un cliente. Además, ¿qué necesidad ay de guardar los links en la base de datos? Alcanza con guardar los usuarios y que se conviertan en URLs a la hora de obtenerlos.

Comment: @Mariano Perdón creo que no me expliqué bien quiero guardar en la base de datos la información que contiene está variable `var user_online = [];` en este caso la información que contiene la variable son los usuarios guardar los usuarios como muestra la base de datos que contiene los tres usuarios de ahí sí amigo cómo indicas guardar los usuarios y que se conviertan en urls

Comment: @Mariano amigo se podría convertir en urls como el ejemplo que me indicastes en jsfiddle.net pero en vez de jquery en PHP

Comment: http://ideone.com/BTroPo Pero realmente creo que deberías **[edit]** la pregunta para que quede claro qué estás preguntando. Concentrate en 1 sola pregunta y lee [ask]

Comment: @Mariano que debo editar amigo dime que está mal para que la pregunta sea clara. No puedo generar enlace si no guardo los datos que contiene la variable `user_online = [];` aquella variable guarda el nombre del usuario ejemplo: Pedro, Jaun, Carlos sin ello como género entonces las urls debajo de los comentarios dice trasladar debate al chat podemos aser aquello.

Comment: @Mariano concentrarme en una sola cosa, cómo guardo a la base de datos la información que almacena esta variable `var user_online = [];` que son los nombres de los usuarios. Cómo planteó el código para guardar a la base de datos las información que almacena.

Comment: @Mariano acabó de editar la pregunta te parece que está bien así mil disculpas si la pregunta no fue clara revisaré cuidadosamente las formas correctas de crear preguntas :) Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar un array de JavaScript, usando AJAX de jQuery, recibirla en PHP y grabarla en MySQL, se utilizan los siguientes pasos:

#### 1. Supongamos un HTML así:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="grabarbd.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Grabar en BD" onclick="grabarBD();">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### 2. En `grabarbd.js`, enviar el array por POST

```js
function grabarBD() {
    // Datos como tiene el usuario
    var user_online = ["Pedro", "Juan", "Carlos"];
    var id = 1; //el id con el que quieras guardar

    // Convertir a objeto
    var data = {};
    data.user_online = user_online;
    data.id = id;

    // enviar por POST mediante AJAX
    var url = 'grabarbd.php';   //este es el PHP al que se llama por AJAX
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,   //acá están todos los parámetros (valores a enviar) del POST
        success: function(response){
            // Se ejecuta al finalizar
            //   mostrar si está OK en consola
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

#### 3. En `grabarbd.php`, se recibe el valor y se graba en la base

```php
if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['user_online']) && !empty($_POST['user_online'])) {
    // Datos recibidos
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $user_online = implode(', ', $_POST['user_online']);

    //Datos de conexión a la base
    $host = "localhost";
    $usuario = "usuario";
    $clave = "clave";
    $basedatos = "NombreBaseDeDatos";
    $tabla = "NombreDeTabla";

    // Conectar a la base
    //  la variable $myslqi contendrá el objeto con la conexión
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
        die( "Error al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
    }

    // insert en la base
    $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (id, User_Online) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $sentencia->bind_param("is", $id, $user_online );
    $sentencia->execute();

    // Cerrar la conexión
    $sentencia = null;
    $mysqli = null;

    // Devolver una respuesta a JavaScript
    echo "Se grabó el id = $id, con User_Online = $user_online";
}
```

**Nota:** este es un ejemplo que muestra la funcionalidad básica. Se le debe agregar el tratamiento de posibles errores.

Comment: no se utilizar PDO puedes mostrar el ejemplo en mysqli no me queda muy claro el código jQuery que me acabas de indicar `var id ` significa que tengo que cambiarlo manualmente recuerda que la variable `user_online` permanece vacía es una variable global que por medio de arays se almacena los nombres de los usuarios.

Comment: que lastima que no se programar aún PDO :( quedé en las mismas pero gracias por responder buen día.

Comment: Pensé que con la etiquetas PHP, jQuery, MySQLi no era necesario especificar más detalle. Perdón por la duda del `var id ` entiendo fue un error por parte mía está perfecto el problema sólo consiste ahora en el código PDO. Puedes añadir un comentario en el código jQuery de llamar el ajax por medio de un botón de publicar comentario este ejemplo lo podría implementar también para un contador de comentarios pero el problema sería el PDO voy a leer el enlace gracias

Comment: espero adaptarme al sitió dedicaré el día entero en leer todo la información sobre el uso del sitio gracias.

Comment: @May Editado usando `mysqli`

Comment: muchas gracias amigo te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Buen día amigo, el ejemplo me funciono perfectamente pero te acordás que os dije que me serveria el ejemplo para crear también el contador de comentario pero sólo me registra un solo dato no más intente deshabilitando todos los `id` tanto del código jQuery y el PHP pero deshabilitando aquella función no registra nada en la base de datos podrías comentar que cambios debo hacer o tengo que crear una nueva pregunta de registrar datos continuos en una id primaria saludos :) disculpa la molestia.