# ¿Cómo insertar datos en la base de datos mediante Ajax y jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estoy tomando base de una la pregunta

> [¿Cómo enviar los datos que alamacena una variable en jQuery mediante AJAX a un PHP y guardar en la base de datos con MySQLi?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24230/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-los-datos-que-alamacena-una-variable-en-jquery-mediante-ajax-a-un-p/24247#24247)

Pero el problema es que para mis datos no me funciona.

Estoy haciendo una página en el que un estudiante ingresa con el usuario y contraseña, el usuario queda almacenado hasta que cierra sesión, por ende todo lo que haga dentro queda con su usuario.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es poner una pregunta y que ellos elijan una de las 5 opciones, y que apenas elijan la opción lo suba automáticamente a la base de datos.

Aquí el código de lo que estoy tratando de hacer

**1) Las opciones de pregunta que vienen en `example.php` junto con el array POST**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**LA CAPITAL DE ESPAÑA ES:**

```
Barcelona: <input type="radio" id="p1" name="n1" value="Opción 1"><br>
Atenas: <input type="radio" id="p2" name="n2" value="Opción 2"><br>
Berlin: <input type="radio" id="p3" name="n3" value="Opción 3"><br>
Madrid: <input type="radio" id="p4" name="n4" value="Opción 4"><br>
Bogota: <input type="radio" id="p5" name="n4" value="Opción 4"><br>
```

**Acá la parte del array POST**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
          $(':radio').click(function() {
            $(':radio').prop("disabled", true);
            valor= $(this).val();
            /*Desde aquí se invoca la función que agrega a la BD
              y se pasa el valor del radio seleccionado
              Ejemplo: agregarDatos(valor);*/
            //agregarDatos(valor);
            console.log("Aquí se envía a la base de datos el valor de : "+valor); 
        });

        //console.log(datos);

        function agregarDatos(valor)
            { 
            //console.log("Aquí envías a la BD: "+valor); 
            /*Desde esta función se puede implementar una llamada a Ajax 
                que enviará la información del radio seleccionado a la BD*/ 

            /*La petición Ajax sería algo así*/ 
            usuario= '<?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]; ?>'; 
            datos={usuario: usuario, respuesta: valor}; 
            console.log(datos); 

            /*comentado temporalmente*/
            var request = $.ajax({ 
                url: "agregar.php", //Archivo de servidor que inserta en la BD 
                method: "POST", 
                data: datos, 
                dataType: "json" 
            }); 

            request.done(function( data ) { 
                console.log("Se agregaron los datos: "+data); 
            }); 

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) { 
                alert( "Error petición Ajax: " + textStatus ); 
            }); 
            }
        });

    </script>
```

**2) En `agregar.php` viene la conexión a la base de datos**

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['respuesta']) && !empty($_POST['respuesta'])) 
    {
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $respuesta = implode(', ', $_POST['respuesta']);

    //Datos de conexión a la base de datos
    $host       = "localhost";
    $usuario    = "root";
    $clave      = "";
    $basedatos  = "evaluacion";
    $tabla      = "pregunta";

    // Conectar a la base
    //  la variable $myslqi contendrá el objeto con la conexión
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) 
        {
        die( "Error al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
        }

    // insert en la base
    $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $sentencia->bind_param("is", $usuario, $respuesta );
    $sentencia->execute();

    // Cerrar la conexión
    $sentencia = null;
    $mysqli = null;

    // Devolver una respuesta a JavaScript
    echo "Se grabó el usuario = $usuario, con respuesta = $respuesta";
    }
?>
```

Comment: En vez de: `$respuesta = implode(', ', $_POST['respuesta']);` creo que debería ser: `$respuesta = $_POST['respuesta'];` y aquí: `$sentencia->bind_param("si", $usuario, $respuesta );` ya que `usario` es string `s` y respuesta es integer `i`.

Comment: Ya lo cambié, pero sigue sin aparecer nada en la base de datos.

Comment: descarta comentando la linea del bind_param y agrega las variables en el prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (".$usuario.", '".$respuesta."')");

Comment: Hola @CarlosOrtiz, te has fijado que la variable `$usuario` la tienes primero como el parámetro recibido y luego como **root** no ? Aquí; `$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];` y aquí `$usuario    = "root";`

Comment: Muy fina la observación de @Edu3D, no me había dado cuenta de que había dos variables `$usuario` para dos usos diferentes. En cuanto a lo del `bind_param` en la respuesta aceptada, es importante señalar que no es recomendable pasar los datos directamente a la BD ya que da la posibilidad de Inyección SQL, lo más seguro es escribir la consulta con los signos `?, ?` y pasar los valores con `bind_param`... no sé cómo ha quedado el código al final, por eso lo comento. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ha apuntado @juliocpiro  descomenta esta  línea del jQuery:

```
        agregarDatos(valor);
```

de lo contrario la función que hace la petición Ajax no se ejecutará nunca.

---

Prueba el código de esta forma. He ido controlando lo que ocurre en cada posibilidad, construyendo siempre un `$json` que será la respuesta del servidor.  Luego en el `done` de la llamada Ajax podrás ver lo que ha ocurrido en `agregar.php` y actuar en consecuencia.

```
/*Verificar que estén todos los datos*/
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['respuesta']) && !empty($_POST['respuesta'])) 
{
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $respuesta = $_POST['respuesta'];
    //Datos de conexión a la base de datos
    $host       = "localhost";
    $usuario_db    = "root"; //Había dos variables $usuario
    $clave      = "******NO-OLVIDES-PONER-AQUI-TU-CLAVE-EN-EL-CODIGO-REAL****";
    $basedatos  = "evaluacion";
    $tabla      = "pregunta";

    // Conectar a la base
    //  la variable $myslqi contendrá el objeto con la conexión
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario_db, $clave, $basedatos);

    /*Verificar si la conexión se realizó*/
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) 
    {
        $error="Error al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        $json=array(1=>$error);
    }

    // insert en la base
    $sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (?, ?)");

    /*Verificar si la sentencia se preparó*/
    if ($sentencia)
    {
        /*Esta parte es MUY IMPORTANTE para darle seguridad al código 
         *evitando la Inyección SQL
         *las letras "si"  deben coincidir con el tipo de dato
         *que tiene la columna en la base de datos
         *aquí suponemos que usuario es string, por eso hay una s
         *y que respuesta es integer, por eso hay una i
        */
        $sentencia->bind_param("si", $usuario, $respuesta );
        $sentencia->execute();

        /*Verificar si se insertaron datos*/
        if ($sentencia->affected_rows)
        {
            $json=array(2=>$sentencia->affected_rows);              
        }else{
            $json=array(3=>"Ningún dato insertado");

        }

        // Cerrar la $sentencia
        $sentencia = null;

    }else{
            $json=array(4=>"Error en la instrucción SQL");

    }

    //Cerrar la conexión
    $mysqli = null;

}else{
            $json=array(5=>"La petición ajax no envió los datos correctamente");    
}

/*Respuesta que manejará la petición Ajax en examen.php*/
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Parece que subiera, pero en la consola aparece así `Se agregaron los datos: [object Object]`

Comment: Antes de agregar éste código que escribiste acá, con el que tenía, en la consola me aparecía lo siguiente: `{usuario: "cortiz", respuesta: "1"}` pero me aparecía una alerta diciendo `Error petición Ajax: parsererror`, igual en ninguno de los dos casos me subió nada a la BD

Comment: Y agregué esto `prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (".$usuario.", '".$respuesta."')");` y ya me parece en la consola lo siguiente: `{usuario: "cavasquez", respuesta: "3"}` - `Aquí se envía a la base de datos el valor de : 3` y por último `Se agregaron los datos: [object Object]` antes me aparecía 1/3, o 2/3, pero ahora ya me aparecen todas.

Comment: Aunque funcione, esta no es la mejor manera de hacerlo, ya que enviar los datos directamente en la consulta es un grave riesgo de Inyección SQL, @CarlosOrtiz revisa mi respuesta y los comentarios que he puesto. Con el código como está, si cambias la consulta a: `prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (?,?)");  y pones el `bind_param`  así: `bind_param("si", $usuario, $respuesta );`  asumiendo que `usuario`  es del tipo `varchar` en la bd y que `respuesta` es del tipo `int` (por eso `"si"`) el código debería funcionar y sería seguro. Si ambos son del tipo `varchar` pones `"ss"`

Comment: ya lo hice así y ya me funciona, sólo que no lo había publicado, pero ya funciona tal cual como me lo pasaste. Muchísimas gracias, pienso montar otra pregunta por si me puedes ayudar. :D

Comment: Bien bien, me alegro, @CarlosOrtiz. Cuando plantees tu pregunta seguro que encontrarás  una buena respuesta de cualquier miembro de la comunidad, pues hay gente muy capacitada aquí respondiendo a preguntas y los otros usuarios también miran las respuestas y comentan si ven algo que no está del todo correcto, de esa manera se logran soluciones óptimas en casi todos los casos. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano pero me refería al tiempo de respuesta, porque necesito terminar eso lo más pronto posible entonces por ese motivo me estreso por querer una respuesta pronta, pero sé que hay una calidad de profesionales en la página que ni me imagino, igual que usted, mil gracias, saludos.

Comment: Plantea la pregunta, la respuesta dependerá de la complejidad del problema y de la disponibilidad de tiempo de cada uno, @CarlosOrtiz. Se intenta ayudar de la mejor manera, a veces es posible en un breve tiempo, a veces no... eso depende de muchos factores. Te recomiendo que seas claro en tu pregunta y así obtendrás una respuesta más rápido. Saludos.

Comment: falta una cosita, y es que si le doy **F5** a la página o refrescar, vuelven a quedar habilitados los radios... ¿Cómo hago para que no se habiliten ni cuando vaya **"Atrás"** ni con **F5** ni con adelante, si no que ya no se pueda modificar nunca después de seleccionado.

Comment: @CarlosOrtiz eso podría responderlo quizá alguien que sea experto en el manejo de sesiones, cookies, etc, en PHP. Lamentablemente no tengo ninguna experiencia en eso. Podría ser una pregunta interesante para el sitio y seguro que alguien te dará una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

En el codigo que publicas esta linea esta comentada, descomentala:

```
//agregarDatos(valor);
```

debe estar

```
agregarDatos(valor);
```

Para que invoque tu funcion que manda el ajax.

Si persiste, descarta comentando la linea del bind_param y agrega las variables en el prepare

**opcional** solo para descartar

```
prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (".$usuario.", '".$respuesta."')");
//$sentencia->bind_param("is", $usuario, $respuesta );
```

Podrias tener alguna incompatibilidad de datos. Por los comentarios donde dices *{usuario: "cavasquez", respuesta: "3"}* se entiende que usuario es `string` entonces la linea bind_param deberia ser:

**solucion**

```
prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, respuesta) VALUES (?, ?)");
$sentencia->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $respuesta );
```

**usuario**
Cambiar nombre de una de estas dos variables, porque en BD llega 'root':

```
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$usuario    = "root";
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo había hecho.

Comment: entonces ya funciona?

Comment: Lee el comentario que hice en la respuesta anterior. Sobre lo que aparece en consola.

Comment: ah ok pusiste los datos directamente en el "prepare" te lo sugeri en el comentario de la publicacio  porque pense que podrias tener incompatibilidad de datos, revisa esa parte si deseas regresar al "bin_param". Agregare eso en mi respuesta. Suerte

Comment: No entendí lo del  `bin_param`

Comment: la linea del bind_param que pone las variables cuando usas "?,?" en la consulta. como has puesto directamente las variables la linea del bind_param ya esta de mas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65243/discussion-between-carlos-ortiz-and-juliocpiro).

Comment: ¿Osea que elimino el ".$usuario.", ".$respuesta." del values? y lo dejo ?,?

Comment: actualice la respuesta con esa explicacion