# NO GUARDA DATOS EN AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Buenas, queria saber porque no guarda mis datos cuando estoy usando ajax

Creo la funcion y puse onclick en el boton

```
<script>
function saveData(){
    var dni = $('#cli_dni').val();
    var nombres = $('#cli_nom').val();
    var apellidos = $('#cli_ape').val();
    var direccion = $('#cli_dir').val();
    var celular = $('#cli_cel').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "conexion.php?p=add",
        data: "cli_dni="+dni+"&cli_nom="+nombres+"&cli_ape="+apellidos+"&cli_dir="+direccion+"&cli_cel="+celular,
    });
}
</script>
```

y luego

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=systemfarma','root',''); 
$page = isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';
if($page=='add'){
    $dni = $_POST['cli_dni'];
    $nombres = $_POST['cli_nom'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['cli_ape'];
    $direccion = $_POST['cli_dir'];
    $celular = $_POST['cli_cel'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into clientes values('',?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->$bindParam(1,$dni);
    $stmt->$bindParam(2,$nombres);
    $stmt->$bindParam(3,$apellidos);
    $stmt->$bindParam(4,$direccion);
    $stmt->$bindParam(5,$celular);
    $stmt->execute();
}else if($page=='edit'){

}else if($page=='del'){

}else{

}
```

?>

Esta es el nuevo codigo que reemplace por el otro pero al parecer no funciona mi boton sale como bloquedo... 
$(document).ready(function(){
    load(1);
});

```
$("#guardar_clientes").submit(function(event){
    $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);
    var parametros = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/registro_cliente.php",
        data: parametros,
        beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultado_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
        },
            success: function(datos){
                $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
                $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
                    load(1);
            }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: 1. Pon el código HTML, no se sabe cuál es el botón del que hablas, en tu jQuery hay un botón que aparece desactivado. 2. Aquí `$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into clientes values('',?,?,?,?)");` te falta un signo de `?` ya que estás enviando 5 parámetros más abajo. 3. En cuanto a la petición Ajax, sugiero que la hagas como muestra [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100463/29967) es la forma recomendada por jQuery. La parte del PHP la puedes manejar más o menos como dice [la respuesta a esa misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100478/29967)

Answer (score 0):

Verifica si estas recibiendo los datos que envias al php, utiliza var_dump para eso. Es bueno que comentes el error que transmite al intentar guardar la informacion para asi tener mas datos y poder ayudarte.

Yo para enviar la informacion de un formulario via ajax utilizo el siguiente procedimiento:

```
 $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url : varurl,
                datatype:'json',
                data : formu.serialize(),
                success : function(resul){
                 ...
                }

            });
```

Comment: Intente con estos codigos lo dejare arriba