# Insertar en base de datos con JavaScript y php

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, html5

estoy intentando insertar en la base de datos. El funcionamiento sería darle al botón "Apuntarse" y que al darle se insertara el usuario y el id de la quedada a la base de datos a la vez que se desactiva el botón y se activa el botón de "Desapuntarse"(para que quede más claro, si un botón está activado el otro se desactiva)

He intentado mil cosas,la última prueba fue con AJAX pero entre que no sé usarlo bien y que no estoy segura de que funcione ...

Adjunto mi código:
-sel_quedada.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/w3cssgeneral.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/estilo-ocio.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/apuntarse.js"></script>
<title>MEET A MATE</title>
</head>

<body class="color-fondo">
<div class="w3-content w3-sand">

<?php 
    require("codesincss/includes/comun/cabecera.php"); 
    require("codesincss/includes/comun/sidebarIzq.php"); 
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $desc = $_GET['desc'];
    $local = $_GET['local'];
    $fini = $_GET['fini'];
    $org = $_GET['org'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $tipo = 0;
?>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-top" id="contenedor-general">
        <div class="w3-card w3-container w3-white" id="sel-residencia">
            <h2 class='subt'><?php echo $nombre ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $desc ?></p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw w3-large w3-text-dark-blue"></i><?php echo $local; ?></p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw w3-large w3-text-dark-blue"></i><?php echo $fini; ?></p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-link fa-fw w3-large w3-text-dark-blue"></i><?php echo $org; ?></p>
            <div class ="w3-margin-bottom">
            <input type="button" id = "apuntarse" onclick = "myAjax()" class="w3-button w3-dark-blue" value="Apuntarse" />
            <input type="button" id = "desapuntarse" class="w3-button w3-dark-blue" value="Desapuntarse" />
            <p><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw w3-large w3-text-dark-blue"></i><?php echo "Participantes" ?> </p>

            <script>
            botones();
            </script>


            </div>


        </div>

    <div class = "w3-container w3-white w3-card w3-row-padding w3-margin-top" id="coment-residencia">
        <h4>Comentarios</h4>
            <?php
            require("codesincss/procesarComentarios.php");
            $lista = procesarComentarios::getComentarios("$id", 0);
            if (!empty(current($lista))) {
                for ($i=0; $i < count($lista); $i++) {
                    $comentario = $lista[$i]['Comentario'];
                    $valoracion = $lista[$i]['Valoracion'];
                    ?>

                    <div class="comentarios">
                        <p class="w3-margin-left">Valoracion: <?php echo $valoracion; ?> </p>
                        <p class="w3-margin-left" ><?php echo $comentario; ?> </p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
    </div>


    <?php
    include("codesincss/includes/comun/comentario.php");
    if (isset($_SESSION["esAdmin"]) and  $_SESSION['esAdmin']){
        echo " <p><a id = 'detalles-general' href = 'borrarEvento.php?id=$id&tipo=$tipo'>Eliminar evento</a></p>";
        echo " <p><a id = 'detalles-general' href = 'modificarQuedada.php?id=$id'>Modificar evento</a></p>";
    }
    include("codesincss/includes/comun/sidebarDer.php"); 
    include("codesincss/includes/comun/pie.php"); 
    ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

-apuntarse.js

```
    function botones(){

    var buttonD = $('#desapuntarse');
    var buttonA = $('#apuntarse');

    $(buttonD).attr('disabled','disabled');

    buttonA.click(function(){

        alert("Te has apuntado al evento");
       $(buttonA).attr("disabled", "disabled");
       $(buttonD).removeAttr("disabled");


     }
     );

    buttonD.click(function(){
        alert("Te has desapuntado del evento :( ");
        $(buttonD).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(buttonA).removeAttr("disabled");

     }
     );
     }

      function apuntarse(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
        url : "procesarApuntarse.php",
    });

  }

          function myAjax() {
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
       url: 'procesarApuntarse.php/ajax.php',
       data:{action:'call_this'},
       success:function(html) {
         alert(html);
       }

        });
     }
```

-procesarapuntarse.php

```
          <?php
        require_once "includes/config.php";
        function apuntarseAEvento(){
    $app = Aplicacion::getSingleton();
    $mysqli = $app->conexionBd();

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['idUser'];

    /*$app = Aplicacion::getSingleton();
    $mysqli = $app->conexionBd()*/;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO partecipantes (ID_Ocio, ID_Usuario, Nombre_Publico)
                VALUES ('$id', '$idUsuario', '1')";
    $mysqli->query($sql) or die ($mysqli->error. " en la línea ".(__LINE__));

    }
     ?>
```

Comment: Hola ¿Y no deberías consultar a la base de datos si la persona está apuntada o no para decidir que botón mostrar?

Comment: Efectivamente, lo más fácil sería hacer esto con Ajax. Al principio cuesta entender un poco el funcionamiento de Ajax, pero una vez aprendido todo resulta fácil. El problema principal que yo veo es una confusión entre las funciones `apuntarse` y `myAjax`. Esta última es la que más se aproxima a un funcionamiento *normal* de Ajax, pero tiene errores, por ejemplo la url: `procesarApuntarse.php/ajax.php` ¿por qué la pones así si el archivo que procesará los datos es `procesarApuntarse.php`? Luego, la data está vacía: `data:{action:'call_this'}`

Comment: Creo que primero necesitas aclararte un poco sobre cómo funciona Ajax, pues luego será más fácil centrarte en la lógica de los botones de tu formulario. Y más tarde tendrás que aplicar medidas de seguridad a nivel de PHP, pues la consulta `INSERT INTO` que tiene es vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL.  [En esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/100463/29967) se trató un tema parecido al tuyo. El código Ajax de la pregunta es correcto y en la respuesta se explican algunas cosas sobre la inserción de datos en el servidor. Creo que pregunta y respuesta pueden serte de gran ayuda.