# Ejecutar query MYSQL al presionar un botón

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta tabla que me muestra un listado de torneos disponibles para un usuario. Lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario al apretar el botón del trofeo se ejecute una query (esta aumentará el número de "inscritos" que ya tiene una query COUNT).

Mi botón es:

```
<td><button type="submit" name="btn_inscribir"><img src="img/trofeo.png"></button></td>
```

La función que quiero que se ejecute es:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_inscribir'])) {
    $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    $idTorneo = $_POST['idTorneo'];
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO inscritos (idUser, idTorneo) VALUES ('$idUser', '$idTorneo')");
    header('location: torneos.php');
}
```

Al presionar el botón, nada sucede, también he intendado de la siguiente forma:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_inscribir'])) {
    inscribirse();
}
function inscribirse() {
    global $db;
    $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    $idTorneo = $_POST['idTorneo'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO inscritos (idUser, idTorneo) VALUES ('$idUser', '$idTorneo')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    header('location: torneos.php');
}
```

Los datos ya mostrados en la columna "Inscritos" fueron insertados manualmente en phpmyadmin para verificar la query COUNT.

Answer (score 2):

tu archivo html debe quedar asi, solo cambia el action a tu archivo php

```
<form action="tuarchivo.php" method = "post">
<td><button type="submit" name="btn_inscribir"><img 
src="img/trofeo.png"></button></td>
</form>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, gracias por el apoyo, cuando publiques código y que este se vea formateado selecciónalo y presiona `ctrl + k`

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionar. En caso de que no llegue a ser así deberías de revisar que tu base de datos aunque no este ingresando datos como lo son el torneo te agregue los id a la base de datos, para esto pon que el id sea auto numérico para evitarte tener que estar colocando el id manualmente y que en un futuro esto pueda causarte algún conflicto.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_inscribir'])) {
    $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    $idTorneo = $_POST['idTorneo'];
    mysqli_real_query($db, "INSERT INTO inscritos (idUser, idTorneo) VALUES ('$idUser', '$idTorneo')");
    header('location: torneos.php');
}
```

El único cambio que le hice de momento a tu código fue cambiar tu método `mysqli_query` por `mysqli_real_query`. Asegúrate de que en el html el botón se encuentra dentro de una etiqueta form y que esta esta usando el método POST o de otra forma jamas de ejecutara el código por muy bien escrito que este.

Comment: @Lyonknows acabo de editar mi respuesta al final mencionandote algunas cosas que debes de tener en cuenta, deberias de compartir tambien la seccion de tu codigo que ejecuta este boton en el html, me refiero a lo que es el form en donde se supone que se debe de encontrar el boton

Comment: Es posible ejecutar una acción con un botón dentro de una tabla? de ser no, como recomendarías cambiar el botón para que no altere el diseño? Saludos

Comment: He removido el botón dentro de la tabla y lo agregue a un formulario, el detalle es que ahora solo aparece un solo botón por lo que ahora no encuentro la forma de seleccionar un torneo específico para registrarse a él.

Comment: @Lyonknows en ese caso deberías de usar AJAX para subir datos usando Javascript ya que de otra forma jamas podrias subirlos con PHP directamente sin agregar una etiqueta form que controle esa parte de PHP que es el posteo, te anexo un enlace en donde puedes ver como hacer esto que te menciono. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100463/c%C3%B3mo-insertar-datos-en-la-base-de-datos-mediante-ajax-y-jquery

Comment: @Lyonknows Respondiendo a tu siguiente pregunta es que podrias de estar relacionando cada posicion del boton con un id, esa seria la unica opcion posible que veo pero seria cuestion de cual es la mejor forma en que lo implementes, esto ya dependeria de tu logica.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por las referencias