# Enviar valores obtenidos de un table a JSON y Ajax

Tags: html, ajax, json

La pregunta es ¿cómo puedo enviar los datos obtenidos de un table  y pasarlos a Json luego enviarlos por Ajax

```
$("#obtenerDatos").click(function(){
  var mytabla = []
  $("#mytable").find("tbody tr").each(function(index, el) {
    var tr = []
    $(this).find("td").each(function(index, el) {
       tr.push($(this).text())
    });
    mytabla.push(tr)
  });
  console.log(mytabla);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Esta respuesta esta abierta a la comunidad cambios u sugerencia en ella es aceptada para una buena referencia para futuros lectores.

Para enviar un array de JavaScript, usando AJAX de jQuery, recibirla en PHP y grabarla en MySQL, se utilizan los siguientes pasos:

**1. ¿cómo enviar datos que almacena una variable jQuery a php y guardar en la base de datos con MySQLi?**

Esta variable var comunidad = []; se puede imaginar que es una variable global porqué menciona que almacena información u dato. A pesar que permanece así vacía:

```
var comunidad = [];
```

Supongamos que aquella variable contenga esta información almacenado.

```
var comunidad = ["Pedro", "Juan", "Carlos"];
```

La siguiente petición en ajax sería de esta forma:

```
function grabarBD() {
// Datos almacenados nombres de usuarios
var comunidad  = [];

 // Convertir a objeto
 var data = {};
 data.comunidad = comunidad;

 // enviar por POST mediante AJAX
 var url = 'grabarbd.php';   //este es el PHP al que se llama por AJAX
 $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,   //acá están todos los parámetros (valores a enviar) del 
   POST
    success: function(response){
        // Se ejecuta al finalizar
        //   mostrar si está OK en consola
        console.log(response);
    }
   });
   }
```

**grabarbd.php** se recibe el valor y se graba en la base de datos.

```php
if (!empty($_POST['comunidad'])) {
// Datos recibidos
$comunidad = implode(', ', $_POST['comunidad']);

//Datos de conexión a la base
$host = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$clave = "";
$basedatos = "comunidad";
$tabla = "comunidad";

// Conectar a la base
//  la variable $myslqi contendrá el objeto con la conexión
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    die( "Error al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
}

// insert en la base
$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (id, user_comunidad) 
VALUES (?, ?)");
$sentencia->bind_param("is", $id, $comunidad );
$sentencia->execute();

// Cerrar la conexión
$sentencia = null;
$mysqli = null;

// Devolver una respuesta a JavaScript
echo "Se grabó nuevo usuarios a la comunidad";
}
```

Como resultado almacenado en la base de datos:

```
 id    user_comunidad
----  ---------------------
  1     Pedro, Juan, Carlos
```

Referecia la siguinete: [fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24230/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-los-datos-que-alamacena-una-variable-en-jquery-mediante-ajax-a-un-p)

> Nota: La siguiente fuente solo permite añadir un registro en la base de datos en este ejemplo modificado almacena registros continuos a la base de datos tomando en cuenta que el id sea una id primary con el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT.